# What's the best way to get XML file from URL, make some changes and generate new XML of it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to get XML file from external URL, make some changes and generate new XML of it. What is the best way to make it right? jQuery script and then php file with xml content header?

Comment: javascript + php sounds right

Answer (score 0):

It depends. you can use curl to open a connection to that url. get or post and with parameters. and get the result of it. the try to read and parse it.

Then you have a new xml. And you send it to client. in PHP with echo. and you can like set header of content type to make a dynamic generated xml.

search for:

use curl in php

working and parsing xml in php

generating xml with php